# How to remove ^M ^J characters in linux

Tags: c, newline, codeblocks, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have an external machine which send me results in my Raspberry pi. In my emulator Cutecom I have the results line by line without problems. I use Codeblocks and I wrote my own C application to read these data every 10 seconds. But something strange happens. Sometimes I have the results line by line and sometimes I have the strange characters ^M ^J at the end of each line and as a result I have terrible finals results. I think that these EOF characters are because the external machine has developed in Windows.

The good results

```
+PARAMETERS: 45 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (063)
MACHINE_1:(AN=23.45,H=34.56,D=12.34)
```

The bad results

```
+PARAMETERS: 45 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (063)^M^JMACHINE_1:
(AN=21.45,H=33.56,D=10.34)
```

Ok, until here the only problem is the way the command line shows the result but my results are ok. But if I try to use strtok to get some tokens then I have serious problems because of these characters. What can I do? Can I add something to escape these characters?This is the part of the code which I use to read data from the machine

```
char buff[300];
memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
for (;;)
{
  n=read(fd,buff,sizeof(buff));
  sleep(1);
  printf("%s", buff);
  printf("\n");
  ....
  ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just reading blocks of 300 characters, so there is no string termination `\0`.

You'll have to look at `n` to see how much data you have read and then process the data before printing it i.e. look for the `^J^M` and terminate the line,then continue reading the rest of the data.

FYI `^J^M` is Windows line termination (it's just `^J` form linux)

The following should read multiple messages and convert ^ and J to \n and ignore ^M.

Note this uses STDIN, not a serial port.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fd=STDIN_FILENO;
    int i,n;
    int c=0;

    char buff[300];
    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
    for (;;)
    {
        n=read(fd,buff,sizeof(buff));
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
        {
            switch(buff[i])
            {
            case '^':
                if(c) 
                {
                    // ^^ so output first ^
                    putchar('^');
                }
                else
                {
                    // Possible ^M or ^J
                    c++;
                }
                break;

            case 'M':
                if (c)
                {
                    // ignore ^M
                    c=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    // just M 
                    putchar(buff[i]);
                }
                break;

            case 'J':
                if (c)
                {
                    // ^J is \n
                    putchar('\n');
                    c=0;
                }
                else 
                {
                    // just J
                    putchar(buff[i]);
                }
                break;

            default:
                if (c)
                {
                    // ^ followed by other than J or M
                    putchar('^');
                    c=0;
                }

                putchar(buff[i]);
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any example of this kind of implementation??Thanks!

Comment: I'll write one when I get a moment

Comment: As a matter of interest, what device are you reading from (serial?) and why the sleep(1) after the read?

Comment: yes I have a function to open a serial port, a function to configure port with Baudrate. data bits etc and then a function with the above part to read the buffer. The sleep I have it because sometimes I dont have these strange characters but sometimes I have them. Thats why I use it. Furthermore you are right with your comment that the ^M^J character is left over from a previous read. Because in my loop the first time I have exactly the lines and in the second line I have this characters.

Comment: You probably don't need the sleep then. What output do you get with the modification to terminate the string?

Comment: the first time I have +PARAMETERS: 45 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (063)
MACHINE_1:(AN=23.45,H=34.56,D=12.34) and it's ok, the second time +PARAMETERS: 45 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (063)^M^JMACHINE_1:(AN=23.45,H=34.56,D=12.34) and the third time something terrible +PARAMETERS: 45 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (063)^M^J
MACHINE_1:(AN=23.45,H=34.56,^M^JERROR^M^JD=12.34)^M^J

Comment: It looks like the data is backing up between reads, then you're getting several lines at once, you may want to get rid of any sleeps and let read wait for the data, but I'll do a solution that can cope with read multiple messages in one buffer.

Comment: Looking at this, it's weirder than I thought, ^J is \n so I would have expected it to print a newline which implies the actual characters ^ and J are being sent

Answer (score 0):

I think you can still use `strtok()` with this. Just add `^M` and `^J` in the `char *delimiters` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the command "sed -e 's/\^\M$//g' filename"

or I got this from the website.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
while True:
  file = raw_input('Input file name:(input "q" to quit)')
  if file == 'q':
      break
  file_ = open(file).read()
  list_ = list(file_)
  new_file = ''
  for x in list_:
      if x != '^' and x != 'M':
          new_file = new_file + x
  file_ = open(file,'w')
  file_.write(new_file)
  file_.close()
```